# How to use NuGet package (grpc) in mono build script

Tags: c#, mono, grpc

I have to compile some C# code (a language I've never used) on Linux and am struggling how to link a dependence in my mono build script.

I have a build script that was working without a problem

```
GMCS_FLAGS="-unsafe -debug -nowarn:0162 -nowarn:0169"
GMCS_DEFINES="-define:LINUX"
shopt -s nullglob
declare -a SOURCES=( $BRANCHDIR/Engine/*/*.cs $BRANCHDIR/Engine/Utilities/QuadTreeND/*.cs $BRANCHDIR/Utilities/*.cs $BRANCHDIR/Utilities/*/*.cs $BRANCHDIR/ControlSimulator/*.cs $BRANCHDIR/ScenarioGenerator/Transient/*.cs $BRANCHDIR/ScenarioGenerator/Api/*.cs $BRANCHDIR/ScenarioGenerator/Api/*/*.cs  )
declare -a CLEANED

$GMCS_EXECUTABLE $GMCS_FLAGS $GMCS_DEFINES $INCLUDE_C_FLAGS $DEBUG_FLAGS -r:/usr/lib/cli/log4net-2.0.8/log4net.dll -out:$BRANCHDIR/bin/transientScenarioGenerator.exe -resource:$BRANCHDIR/Engine/EventMessages.resources, Engine.EventMessages.resources "${CLEANED[@]}" -main:ScenarioGenerator.Transient.CommandLine
```

Now there is a new dependency on grpc, so I need to link the grpc code in some way. I have used nuget to download the Grpc package but I'm not sure how to link it for the build.

Can I use the NuGet package with the mono compiler?

Is there another way to use Grpc in C# being build on linux?